# How can I tell what limit my cloud function hits when I get a generic "Error: could not handle the request" message?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a cloud function that runs perfectly fine most of the time, but sometimes outputs this generic error.
The function generates PDF documents - sometimes generates them from HTML with Puppeteer (I think this part pretty much always works), sometimes combines other PDFs from invoking itself and loading other URLs into multi-page documents. I can very well imagine that it hits some kind of limit when those documents get long and complex - but I have set both the memory limit and the execution time limit as high as the service allows, and it still fails. Looking at the monitoring graphs, it seems neither execution time nor memory usage graphs are hitting the limits. So the question is: how can I figure out why it fails?

Comment: Maybe something in this article can assist ... 

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting

If you can find an input that always fails, that will probably be used.  I'd also suggest that we look at your GCP Cloud Logging and see if there is additional information written there.  Doing a search on "Could not handle the request" seems to show many possibilities.

Comment: Do you have a sudden spike of Cloud Functions invocation?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, since it invokes itself (by URL) multiple times to build the PDF files that are eventually assembled. Generally serially though, using async/await. FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the function to run on "2nd generation" of the cloud functions feature, where it was possible to grant it more memory. This fixed the issues and it now runs reliably. I still do not quite understand why the graphs under "monitoring" did not hit the indicated memory limits when it failed - would have made it immediately obvious what the problem was. Anyway, 2nd generation FTW.

I post this as an answer just to let anyone struggling with this problem know that the memory usage graphs may not tell the full story, and your cloud function may require more memory even if it does not seem to hit the roof.